# Sudo not asking for password

Tags: networking, sudo, arch-linux

I have a problem with my Antergos installation, when I try to `sudo` a command it won't ask root password:

[image: Screenshot]

Also Ctrl + C won't stop the command. Can't connect to WiFi (Network manager is not running and unpossible to start it).

I don't know what to do. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some features of sudo are network based. So it wouldn't surprise me that a network issue could cause things to hang a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully `sudo`ed in the past 5 minutes? If so, your permission may be cached already.

Could you try another `sudo` command to reduce the failure domain of this problem?
Something simple such as `sudo ls .`